# How to make a request to a node.js app from another website?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, serving

I've been trying to understand how Node.js works in different scenarios. I'm getting a bit hung up on a certain area. As I understand it, Node is very suitable to tasks such as ad serving. In a scenario, similar to google ads, how would the code that a publisher puts on their website make a request to the remote adserver? I've been looking at the http module and seen that one can make requests, but if I understand correctly, that would only work from the node app itself. I'm wondering how other apps and websites can interact and make requests.

I hope this question is clear and concise. I'm just very curious about this and have spent a few weeks researching this and have come up empty handed. Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [`express`](http://expressjs.com/) package for node.js.  This will allow you to implement responses to web requests.